# Has anyone studied the beings of logic from Heidegger's "Time & being" perspective?

Tags: philosophy-of-logic, heidegger

The nature of the word 'logic' differs according to the context where it is used (i.e., Aristotle and Socrates, boolean algebra, symbolic logic, propositional logic, etc.)

Has any philosopher focussed on the 'being' of logic using Heidegger's 'Being & Time' contribution?

Comment: It's necessary to clarify the semantics about his key terminology such as obstinacy to ready-to-hand and present-at-hand, this [post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/89339/meaning-of-these-words-in-heideggers-being-and-time?rq=1) scratched the surface here, for instance. Also there's always an underlying (changing) *mood* assailing the Dasein aka being-in-the world. Thus a possible logic for his non-dual thrown Dasein cannot be context-free classic logic, more like Buddhism's famous dialethestic or [Catuṣkoṭi logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catu%E1%B9%A3ko%E1%B9%ADi)...

Comment: Maybe you can start from [Heidegger on Logic](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/heidegger-on-logic/BED13D9E3420A17FEA4030D8ECFCDDFE).